# Proguard Android How to tell?

Tags: android, export, apk, proguard

I have the Proguard file in my project but I am not sure if it is running when I run through the export wizard tool. Is there a way to check if it actually worked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, Proguard will output some files after it runs like dump.txt, mappings.txt and some others. You should just check those files are refreshed after you compile.